# 64bit instance vs 32bit instance for Apache Web Server on Centos - httpd + PHP5

Tags: php, apache, centos

any recommendation whether to use 64bit instance vs 32bit instance for Apache Web Server on Centos - httpd mainly working with PHP5 ?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a 64bit OS there is no reason to use 32bit software unless you need to load closed-source modules/libraries which only have 32bit versions. That's most likely not the case for you, so go with 64bit.

Comment: Or on a very low end machine where memory usage is very important :).

Comment: Those extremely low end machines usually don't even have 64bit-compatible CPUs...

Comment: Unless they're virtual machines.  Though one could easily argue that if someone is worried about the memory usage of Apache, they probably should not be using Apache, and probably should not be using a 64 bit OS.